# Upload data from cloud storage to bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

[The issue is resolved, Stackoverflow does not allow to delete the question, the issue was a mistmatch in schema]

I have a piece of code which uploads data from cloud storage into bigquery correctly. I run the code locally and works. Now I moved the code to cloud functions, and it fails, could you help me how I can fix it?

The logs : "Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated…"

Comment: Can you share your error logs from cloud logging  and steps to recreate the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check in `Cloud Logging` to have more info on the error, this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#function_terminated) is interesting regarding `Cloud Functions` troubleshooting :

> Function cannot be initialized.  Error: function terminated.
> Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason.  Additional
> troubleshooting information can be found in Logging.